# writing exact text of Jtext area to a file

Tags: java, swing, io, jtextarea, filewriter

hello guys i have a code in my application that save the data on the jtextarea to .txt file.
The problem is when i type multiple line text on my jtextarea and save it to ".txt" file, the the whole data written as one line text.

```
String content = txtDescriptionCity.getText(); //jtextarea

   File file = new File("C:\\Tour v0.1\\Descriptions\\City\\"+txtcityname.getText()+".txt");


            if (!file.exists()) {
                 file.createNewFile();
            }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
```

i want to write the text as it is on the jtextarea... Like this

"Text line one

Text line two

Text line three"

Comment: All the text will come as a single string , You need to split the String and then write it to the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines where entered by Enter, do:

```
content = content.replaceAll("\r?\n", "\r\n");
```

This then uses the real line break under Windows: `\r\n` (CR+LF). A single `\n` is not shown in Notepad. Unlikely though.

If the multiple lines were caused by word wrapping, the case is more difficult.

If by adding spaces,

```
content = content.replaceAll("  +", "\r\n");
```

Comment: @user2136160, don't go to all this trouble. Just use the `write(...)` method that is supported by all Swing text components.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use:

```
textArea.write(...);
```

It will replace new line characters in the Document with the proper new line string for the platform you are using.

Comment: Interesting, as not documented in the javadoc +1,

Answer (score 0):

You can split and then write, in my code i am splitting the string based on "."(fullstops).

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
for (String retval: content.split(".")){
bw.write(retval+".");
bw.newLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we read out the systems line seperator, then we split the content String and write each part of the new String Array to the file. The `new FileWriter(*,true);` garanties that the content is appended.

```
    String seperator = System.lineSeparator();
    String[] lines = content.split("\n");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file ,true);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++){
        writer.append(lines[i]+seperator);

    }
        writer.close();
}
```